# How to Display Hidden Characters While Typing?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vim

How can I configure vim to display hidden characters like tabs or spaces ONLY while those characters are typed? I do not want tabs and/or space replaced with special characters like ">" or "_" when the file is written.

Comment: You're quite welcome, dan0! Too bad you didn't stick around for the answer to your question and will probably never even read this comment. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Checkout `listchars`. This is what I have in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
set list
set listchars=tab:→\ ,extends:»,precedes:«,trail:▒,nbsp:·
```

Show a right arrow for tabs, a semi-filled block for trailing whitespace, and a middot for non-breaking spaces. This is purely for display; the file does not contain those fancy characters.

Answer (score 0):

Drew Neils' Vimcasts are amazing, take a look at this one. It help me made the transition from Textmate to Vim

http://vimcasts.org/episodes/show-invisibles/